# Node.js - get previous url

Tags: node.js

I am a new Node.js developer.
I want to get previous page url in new page.
For example, the first url is http://myurl/page1.
And give an action, url is changed to http://myurl/page2.
Now on page2, how can I get previous url using Node.js.

Please help me.
Alyosha.

Comment: are you looking for `req.headers.referer`?

Answer (score -1):

You have to store in session.

Example

```
app.get('/url1', function(req, res){
  res.send('ok')
  req.session.current_url = 'url1'
});

app.get('/url2', function(req, res){
  res.send('ok')
  req.session.current_url = 'url2'
});
```

And when you need previous url. You can use req.session.current_url varriable.